# New iPhone 6s doesn't have News app

Tags: iphone, news.app

I bought an iPhone 6s recently and my brother did so too, we just come pared them and it appears that my iPhone 6s doesn't have a default News app (the one that can't be deleted) but my brother does. Why is that?

Comment: What OS are they running and which country's app store are they using?

Comment: iOS 9 and country Cyprus

Comment: Change your region to US and reboot your phone.

Answer (score 1):

On the apple forum it states from Sept. 24th that the news app is only available in the US.
Maybe the phone of your brother has a US iTunes store account or was bought there?

Source:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7236616

Comment: Yeah probably the region is the problem cause he set up it as us and I did as Cyprus. I think I'll try restoring it.

Comment: Let us know if that works!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I just changed my region in the settings to United States, which restarted my iPhone when applied and adds the app.